# Multiple await how to

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

I have got this method

```
private async void UCCardHolders_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
   {
      Overlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      await GetOrganizationsAsync();
      await GetSexTypesAsync();
      await GetCitiesAsync();
      await GetClientCategoryTypesAsync();
   }
}
```

But I would like to wait for all of them.
Is it possible?

Comment: you already are

Comment: @JohanP Oh! Fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the same statement, just use [Task.WaitAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Otherwise, your solution already does it - as already mentioned by JohanP

Comment: `WaitAll` is quite a bad suggestion as alternative to `await` (especially if you've noticed tags on the question)... You either should provide good explanation on how to do it safely or not recommend it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know it had the blocking issue that I just read about. And, btw, you should realize that if you know the problems with something - it's not always necessary that everyone else does. I was just trying to help.